# Logic Error (Pythons): Not getting write output but function works?

Tags: python

Inputted:

```
Akash Das
```

Expected return:

```
Das Akash
```

My code is outputting:

```
Da Akash
```

Here's my code:

```
#a
def firstWord(string):
    space = string.find(" ")
    first = string[:space]
    return first

#b
def removeFirst(string):
    space = string.find(" ")
    word = string[space + 1:]
    return word

print(removeFirst("Akash Das"))
#c
def reversePhrase(string):
    reverse = []
    numSpace = string.count(" ")
    reverse.append(firstWord(string))
    while numSpace > 0:
       string = removeFirst(string)
       reverse.insert(0, firstWord(string))
       numSpace -= 1
    return reverse

def printReverse(string):
    for i in reversePhrase(string):
        print (i, end = " ")
#d
def main():
    string = input("Enter a phrase. ")
    print("Your reversed phrase is", end = " ") #call reverse
    printReverse(string)
main()
```

And here's the output:

```
>>> 
Das
Enter a phrase. Akash Das
Your reversed phrase is Da Akash 
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSZ is right, that is simpler. But your problem is in `firstWord`. If the string has no spaces, then `find` will return -1. So `space` will be -1, and `string[:space]` will be `string[:-1]` which is all characters except the last. You just need to check whether you actually found a space:

```
def firstWord(string):
    space = string.find(" ")
    first = string[:space] if space >= 0 else string
    return first
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simplier way:

```
def main():
    string = input("Enter a phrase. ")
    print("Your reversed phrase is", end = " ")
    print(' '.join(reversed(string.split())))
main()
```

output

```
Enter a phrase. Akash Das
Your reversed phrase is Das Akash
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking care of the case when find returns -1, it happens when it does not find " ".

Try:

```
#a
def firstWord(string):
    space = string.find(" ")
    if space >=0:
        first = string[:space]
    else:
        first = string
    return first
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
>>> import re
>>> name = 'Harsha Biyani'
>>> s = re.split('\W',s)
>>> s.reverse()
>>> ' '.join(s)
'Biyani Harsha'
```